# How to create a PHP calendar based on selected month and year listboxes

Tags: php, calendar

I'm currently working on a page that create a calendar using PHP based on a month and a year selected from the user. I used listboxes to accomplish this action but somehow it does not seem to work properly.

Here is the HTML form I used

```
<div id="calendar">
                <form method="post" action="calendar.html">
                    <label>Year: </label>
                    <select name="year">
                        <option>2000</option>
                        <option>2001</option>
                        <option>2002</option>
                        <option>2003</option>
                        <option>2004</option>
                        <option>2005</option>
                        <option>2006</option>
                        <option>2007</option>
                        <option>2008</option>
                        <option>2009</option>
                        <option>2010</option>
                        <option>2011</option>
                        <option>2012</option>
                        <option>2013</option>
                        <option>2014</option>
                        <option>2015</option>
                    </select>

                    <label>Month: </label>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />

                </form>
            </div>
```

Here is the code of the PHP

```
<?php   

    $year = $_POST{"year"};
    $month = $_POST{"month"};
    $year = date("Y", $year);
    $month = date("m", $month);

    $firstDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);

    $title = date("F", $firstDay);
    $dayOfWeek = date("D", $firstDay);

    switch($dayOfWeek) {
        case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
        case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
        case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
        case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
        case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
        case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
        case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;
    }

    $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

    echo "<table class='centertable'>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan=7>" . $title . " " . $year . "</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr><tr>";

    $dayCount = 1;
    while ($blank > 0) {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        $blank--;
        $dayCount++;
    }

    $dayNum = 1;
    while ($dayNum <= $daysInMonth) {
        if (date("d") != $dayNum) {
            echo "<td>" . $dayNum . "</td>";
            $dayNum++;
            $dayCount++;
        } else {
            echo "<td class='currentdate'>" . $dayNum . "</td>";
            $dayNum++;
            $dayCount++;
        }
        if ($dayCount > 7) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $dayCount = 1;
        }
    }

    while ($dayCount > 1 and $dayCount <= 7) {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        $dayCount++;
    }

    echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

I created a CSS class to highlight the current date when I was working on an automatic calendar displaying the current month of viewing.

When I added the listboxes, this does not seem to work anymore. I don't know how but the code I provided above only show the calendar of Jan 1970 regardless of whatever I choose from the listboxes.

Please note that the listboxes and the PHP code are in the same page. I made the submit button refer to the same page so the user can select another month and year if they want to. Also, I want to add a CSS class if the date is today (month and year). This code also highlights date 10 (today) even though the calendar is Jan 1970.

EDIT: I used the wrong word, it should be dropdown list rather than listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 first lines is incorrect:

```
$year = $_POST{"year"};
$month = $_POST{"month"};
```

In php, you must use square brackets for array indexes:

```
$year = $_POST["year"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
```

Confirm if year and month are set properly in your listbox too (name property "year" and "month").

**EDIT:** Based on your HTML form, change form action to:

```
<form method="post" action="calendar.php">
```

Comment/remove lines 3 and 4 of your file:

```
<?php   

$year = $_POST["year"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
//$year = date("Y", $year);
//$month = date("m", $month);
```

Save your file with the name `calendar.php`. It will result in something [like this](https://gist.github.com/gmsantosxl/a5fb69b142e487facc59)

Comment: It is not an array, it's suppose to take only one value for each field: month and year.

Comment: I see, I did not know that. What I thought was $_POST is the same as $_GET and they will get only one single value. Anyways, it doesn't work still. It still shows the calendar of Jan 1970 for some reason. I think the logic and functions I used are the problem but have no idea what kind.

Comment: Your logic seems to be ok. Maybe the problem is your HTML. Can you edit your question with your form?

Comment: I added the HTML form. Please ignore the CSS id or classes.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function below using `$month`, `$year` and `$Monthname` as arguments.

It builds a complete calendar for the specified month, year and Monthname.

Example `draw_calendar(10,2021,'October')`;

```
function draw_calendar($month, $year, $Monthname){

$wd = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); // $wd = weekdaynumber [0|1|...|6] = Sun,Mon,...,Sat
$dim = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); // $dim = days in month 28,29,30 or 31
$calmonth = array_fill(0, 42, "<td data-day=0></td>"); // fill array with 42 defaults, a month can run over 6 weeks max

$day = 1;
for ($i = $wd; $i < $dim + $wd; $i++) {
    $calmonth[$i] = "<td>$day</td>";
    // or $calmonth[$i] = userfunction($day, $month, $year);
    $day++;
}

// build calendar, row1 = Monthname year; row2 = Sun,Mon,...,Sat
$calendar = "<table class=calendar><tr><td colspan=7>$Monthname $year</td></tr>";
$calendar .= "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array('Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat')) . "</td></tr>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($calmonth); $i = $i + 7) // build calendar week by week, optional skip last empty row(s)
{
    $week = implode('', array_slice($calmonth, $i, 7));
    if ($week != str_repeat('<td data-day=0></td>', 7)) {
        $calendar .= "<tr>$week</tr>";
    }
}
$calendar .= "</table>";
return $calendar;
}
```

CSS Style:

```
:root {
--softpurple: #FFCCFF;
--softyellow: #FFFF99;
--softgreen: #CCFFCC;
--mediumpurple: #FF66FF;
--softblue: #99CCFF;
--softorange: #FFCC66;
--darkorange: #FF9933;
--mediumgreen: #33CC33;
--softred: #ff9b9b;}

table.calendar {width:90%;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto; position: relative; border-collapse: collapse;}
table.calendar tr:first-child td {text-align:right;font-size:14pt;margin:0;width:90%;position: relative;margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;}
table.calendar tr:nth-child(2) td {background: purple;color:gold;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;width: calc(100% / 7);border: 1px solid #999; font: 12pt;}
table.calendar tr:nth-child(n+3) td[data-day='9'] {background: silver;color:#444;font-weight: bold;text-align: right;width: calc(100% / 7);border: 1px solid #999; padding-right: 15px; font-size:11pt;pointer-events:none}
table.calendar tr:nth-child(n+3) td[data-day='2'] {background: var(--softred);color:#444;font-weight: bold;text-align: right;width: calc(100% / 7);border: 1px solid #999; padding-right: 15px; font-size:11pt;}
table.calendar tr:nth-child(n+3) td[data-day='1'] {background: var(--softgreen); color:#444;font-weight: bold;text-align: right;width: calc(100% / 7);border: 1px solid #999; padding-right: 15px; font-size:11pt;cursor: pointer;}
table.calendar tr:nth-child(n+3) td[data-day='0'] {background: #eee;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;width: calc(100% / 7);border: 1px solid #999;}
```

Output:

```
<table class="calendar"><tbody><tr><td colspan="7">Oktober 2021</td></tr><tr><td>Zo</td><td>Ma</td><td>Di</td><td>Wo</td><td>Do</td><td>Vr</td><td>Za</td></tr><tr><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-01',2021,10,1,1)">1</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-02',2021,10,2,1)">2</td></tr><tr><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-03',2021,10,3,1)">3</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-04',2021,10,4,1)">4</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-05',2021,10,5,1)">5</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-06',2021,10,6,1)">6</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-07',2021,10,7,1)">7</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-08',2021,10,8,1)">8</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-09',2021,10,9,1)">9</td></tr><tr><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-10',2021,10,10,1)">10</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-11',2021,10,11,1)">11</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-12',2021,10,12,1)">12</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-13',2021,10,13,1)">13</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-14',2021,10,14,1)">14</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-15',2021,10,15,1)">15</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-16',2021,10,16,1)">16</td></tr><tr><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-17',2021,10,17,1)">17</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-18',2021,10,18,1)">18</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-19',2021,10,19,1)">19</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-20',2021,10,20,1)">20</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-21',2021,10,21,1)">21</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-22',2021,10,22,1)">22</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-23',2021,10,23,1)">23</td></tr><tr><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-24',2021,10,24,1)">24</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-25',2021,10,25,1)">25</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-26',2021,10,26,1)">26</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-27',2021,10,27,1)">27</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-28',2021,10,28,1)">28</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-29',2021,10,29,1)">29</td><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-30',2021,10,30,1)">30</td></tr><tr><td title="Vrij" data-day="1" onclick="selectdate('2021-10-31',2021,10,31,1)">31</td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td><td data-day="0"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```